# Thrown exceptions inside several functions and catch them in only one place

Tags: javascript, exception, closures

I have several little functions that can thrown exceptions.

```
var f = function (){
    return {
        f1 : function(var1){
            if ( ! var1){
                throw Error("...");
            }
        },
        f2 : function(var1){
            if ( ! var1){
                throw Error("...");
            }
            f.f1() // calling a local method here
        }
    };
}();
```

How I could catch these exceptions in only one place?

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (e) {
    alert('...')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling them on the same try block

```
try{
   f.f1();
   f.f2();
}catch(e){
   //...
}
```

Comment: +1 THX. But what if I call a local method? (question just edited)

Comment: It doesn't matter. The control flow still counts as being inside the same try-block as f2.

Comment: You meant `var x = f;` ... But this try-catch will run all functions, one behind another. I don't want that. You say that I should write all control flow inside this try-catch? right?

Comment: If you want to catch things in the same catch block you need to put said things in the corresponding try-block. Otherwise, you need to do something completely different that you didn't talk abou tand that probably should be decided on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: `var x = f();` gives error `var x = f;` is OK. Your solution is right as I can call a unique f.init() method that contains all code (http://jsfiddle.net/NomikOS/a3Ku5/4/)
`